# jasmine-node says "0 tests" when there *are* tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I expect this to say "1 test", but it says "0 tests". Any idea why? This is on OS X.

```
$ jasmine-node --verbose my.spec.js
undefined

Finished in 0.001 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped

$ cat my.spec.js
describe("bar", function() {
  it("works", function() {
    expect("foo").toEqual("foo");
  });
});

$ jasmine-node --version
1.11.0  
$ npm --version
1.3.5  
$ node -v
v0.4.12
```

Even if I try to create a syntax error I get the same output:

```
$ cat my.spec.js
it(
$ jasmine-node --verbose --captureExceptions my.spec.js
undefined

Finished in 0.001 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

But if I try to specify a file that doesn't exist, it complains:

```
$ jasmine-node no.spec.js
File: /tmp/no.spec.js is missing.
```

Comment: Added "describe" back in my spec, above, to rule that out as a source of errors. I get the same "0 tests" result even with it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [upgrade to the latest version of nodejs](http://nodejs.org/download/) (currently 0.10.15)

Comment: Alas, with your exact spec and your exact line to run it, I still get the exact same output.

Comment: Why are you running node 0.4?  That's a *really old* version.  We are up to 0.10 and 0.4 is unsupported

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to ask!

Comment: @nirk Now we're talking. Will try updating Node and see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Updated Node to 0.10.15 and now everything works. @nirk, thank you! I'm not very familiar with the world of node, so I specified versions in the hope of feedback like yours. If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Nenad the --matchall is needed if you don't name the file properly.  For example, if your test file is `test.js` then jasmine will get confused

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with this particular question.

Comment: @Nenad it fails in the same way (0 tests ...).  Though in this case, the issue stemmed from an old version of node

Comment: It fails the same way with, or without --matchall. You removed it from answer anyway. All fine.

Answer (score 34):

I also had this problem, it was that I didn't name the file correctly:

> your specification files must be named as **spec.js**, **spec.coffee** or
> **spec.litcoffee**, which matches the regular expression /spec.(js|coffee|litcoffee)$/i; otherwise jasmine-node won't find
> them! For example, sampleSpecs.js is wrong, sampleSpec.js is right.
>
> Source: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

Comment: thanks! that helped me to get jasmine-node running in c9.io ! my files were called .specs.js instead of .spec.js

Answer (score 1):

This problem is in the filename.In jasmine-node, the name of file should end with 'spec' 
*spec.js
eg: helloWorldspec.js or abcspec.js
To quote from documentation:

> your specification files must be named as *spec.js, *spec.coffee or *spec.litcoffee, which matches the regular expression /spec.(js|coffee|litcoffee)$/i; otherwise jasmine-node won't find them! For example, sampleSpecs.js is wrong, sampleSpec.js is right.

Please read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-node#usage).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you miss `describe`?

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Running:

```
c:\Temp>jasmine-node --verbose my.Spec.js

A suite
    contains spec with an expectation

Finished in 0.007 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Actually it has different result. Without describe you get [Error: jasmine.Suite() required]

Comment: If only – that would be helpful. I see the exact same output with or without the describe, sad to say.

Comment: So problem is elsewhere. Your file is not even parsed. It's even possible that your naming confuse (outdated) parser. Try first to name file mySpec.js, then if doesn't work, update Node.

Comment: @HenrikN I just verified that the test spec file must be of the name *.Spec.js or else it won't be parsed.